# An obscure movie featuring a mysterious amphibious monster

Tags: patlabor

I remember very little detail of this movie that randomly aired on TV about a decade ago. Here is what I do remember:

- Dark overtones reminiscent of future noir style. The animation, similarly, is reminiscent of *Ghost in the Shell* or *Ergo Proxy*. The story paces slowly as further details about the monster are given. It was possibly produced in the late '90s to early 2000s, a few years before I watched it.
- The focus of the movie is a rather generic monster: it walks on all fours, is adept at swimming, has olive skin, and a large tail. Also, at some point, it is discovered that it's pregnant.
- One of the main characters is a salty old detective who limps around. I think he has a cane which he hastily abandons in a chase scene (see next bullet).
- There is a climactic point in which the detective is limping through a multilevel construction site whilst being pursued by the monster. There are large exosuits visible in the background (possibly used for construction).
- In this same scene, the construction site undergoes some sort of emergency shutdown, during which the monster's large tail is cut off by a closing door.
- I'm not certain but I believe the monster dies in the end.

I'm sorry I don't remember any more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is an arc in the Patlabor manga storyline. Most likely, you are talking about the [**Patlabor The Movie 3 (2002)**](http://www.themanime.org/viewreview.php?id=510). It has also been adapted in the original late '80s OVA.

Comment: That's it! Wow, from looking at the trailer I left out a lot of things in my description. Not knowing what this movie was has irked me for a while now. Thank you!